# Android detect Bluetooth disconnect immediately

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to detect the disconnection of a Bluetooth device *immediately* after it has happened (1 second max), typically in a "device too far" scenario. Currently I can detect it with a `BroadcastReceiver` by getting a `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`, but it takes about 20 seconds to fire... it'd be faster to set a timeout myself, but I think there should be a way to do it at lower level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not do it at a higher level? Bluetooth timeout takes a while - it is inherent with the RF technology.

What about sending a message once per second? If no reply -> **disconnected**

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing up until now, once per second is acceptable. I thought doing it al lower level would be faster since it should be aware of the connection at all times... I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Yep, there are some timeouts in the Bluetooth specs, and they are customizable, but you would consume too much power for nothing. Plus it's hard/impossible to get to them. And since I was correct, no harm in voting up! :D

Comment: @Radu your answer! is low quality, so must add some code or detailed description in it

Comment: @Hamad you could just add a TimerTask or an Asynctask to do it...come on